# Adding hoverIntent or delay x milliseconds to bootstraps popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there a way to *delay bootstraps popover from showing for x milliseconds*?

Maybe I missed it, but I haven't found it yet, and I want to use Bootstraps popover as a tooltip for CRUD icons in a grid where I show these on each row. 
When the user now hovers over all these icons it keeps flashing on and on off. 
Hence I'd like to define a *delay* / *hoverIntent* so it only shows when the user stops over an icon.

Is this possible in angular-ui-bootstrap? This is what I currently have :

```
<button 
    ng-click="release(row)" 
    class="btn btn-mini"  
    popover="Release account" 
    popover-trigger="mouseenter">
    <i class="icon-trash"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this is silly.. 5 minutes after I created this question I found the solution in the angular-ui documentation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover/docs).

In the list of popover attributes there is this one:

- **popover-popup-delay**: *For how long should the user have to have the mouse over the element before the popover shows (in milliseconds)? Defaults to 0.*

so, my html code just had to be changed into:

```
<button 
    ng-click="release(row)" 
    class="btn btn-mini"  
    popover="Release account" 
    popover-trigger="mouseenter"
    popover-popup-delay=200>
    <i class="icon-trash"></i>
</button>
```

I hope adding this as an answer saves someone elses time....

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes, I'll do so as soon as the 48 hour wait period is over (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer)